# Обработка форм django

Tags: python, django

Разбираюсь с django CBV и у меня возник такой вопрос:

В шаблон в функции get() передается две формы: `order_form` и `review_form`.

Получается я должен обрабатывать эти формы через функцию post?
Если да, то как мне описать функцию чтобы отдельно обрабатывать каждую форму?

Comment: Во-первых, если используете CBV, то обрабатывать надо в методах `form_valid` и `form_invalid`. Во-вторых, не нарушайте _принцип единственной ответственности_, у каждой формы должен быть свой обработчик.

Comment: Понял. Благодарю! :)