# Обработка разных форм Django

Tags: python, django

Подскажите пожалуйста способ, как мне правильно обрабатывать формы.

То есть у меня в шаблоне есть две разные формы, одна из которых заполняется и данные записываются в БД. Как мне определить, какая форма была заполнена и обработать именно эту форму?

Comment: form.is_valid()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Каждому `submit` назначить свое `name` (имя), а во `view` получать этот `name` через POST/GET, в зависимости от того через какой метод у вас отправляется форма, и обрабатывать нужную. Например:

```html
<form>
  ...
  <input type="submit" name="form1" ... >
</form>

<form>
  ...
  <input type="submit" name="form2" ... >
</form>
```

Затем во `views.py` делаем как-то так (напр., форма отправлена через POST):

```python
if 'form1' in request.POST:
    form1 = FormOne(request.POST)
    # ...
else:
    form1 = FormOne()

if 'form2' in request.POST:
    form2 = FormTwo(request.POST)
    # ...
else:
    form2 = FormTwo()

ctx['form1'] = form1
ctx['form2'] = form2

return render_to_response('example/template.html', ctx)
```

Comment: В таком случае мне приходит вот такая штука: 

  <QueryDict: {'first_name': ['Петя'], 'last_name': ['Петров'], 'review_text': ['Отзыв'], 'review_form': ['Submit']}>

  То есть мне через dict.keys() определять имя формы? Или как то покруче можно?

Comment: @Antoxer Обновил ответ, добавив код `views.py`.

Answer (score 2):

И [снова](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/949331/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC-django#comment1581699_949331): у каждой формы должен быть свой обработчик

```
<form action="{% url 'first_form_handler' %}" method="post">
    {{ first_form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>

<form action="{% url 'second_form_handler' %}" method="post">
    {{ second_form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```